# How to make a rotating plane rotate (move) an object sitting on it

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics

I'm trying to make a car (or any object) in rotate when sitting on a plane surface or inside a tube shape. Currently the car acts like it has 0 grip on those surfaces (even tough the car moves without any problems when accelerating, but the objects don't move the car)

What I've tried so far:

- putting a Physics Material on the tube & plane but has no effect
- tuning the parameters of the Physics Material, no effect
- marking the animation's Update Mode of the tube and plane as "Animate Physics", no effect
- increasing the traction of the car (uses RCC), no effect
- increasing the mass of the car..nothing
- increasing mass of wheels, nothing
- tried googling the problem, either didn't write the right terms or just couldn't find anything

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using the plane as a parent of the GameObject you're trying to move?

Comment: How are you rotating the plane?

Comment: @Eliasar I did now, and it did exactly what I imagined, it rotates the car no matter where it is on the map, like the Sun makes the Earth rotate. That's not what I want, at all. And if I parent it to the tube it makes it rotate like the tube. Was funny to watch tough.

Comment: @Eddge Both objects have an animation that rotates them on the corresponding axes, animations made in Unity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rotate the plane and the tube using their `Rigidbody` with the `AddTorque` method or similar. If you just rotate them via their transform it has no effect on the physics system.

Comment: To expand on this: I didn't even have a rigidbody on the rotating objects. I added a Rigidbody, a Constant Force, locked the needed axis on the Rigidbody, and disabled the Animator. Now when I put the car or box on the objects it works exactly as needed! Thanks!